# How to fix a 404 error pulling data from MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

I am working on a backend for my React app that pulls the data from MongoDB, but receiving a 404 error whenever I try to launch the app.

Here is how I added `axios` in App.js file:

[image]

Here is the route in server.js file:

[image]

But I am getting this error whenever I try to open the main page of the app:

[image]

When I launch the database using `node server.js` command, the database is started successfully.

I don't have much experience for troubleshooting such errors - can anyone please offer some advice?

Comment: did you use router  ?

Comment: in browser did you get same error ?

Comment: Yes, I am getting this error in browser. Where would you suggest to use router?